# How to mod rewrite for folder and subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the code below to redirect the url below :

[www.example.com/100](http://www.example.com/100)

to

[www.example.com/index.php?cod=100](http://www.example.com/index.php?cod=100)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?cod=$1 [L]
```

It works, but what if i want to redirect this url :

[www.example.com/100/200](http://www.example.com/100/200)

to :

[www.example.com/index.php?cod=100&othercod=200](http://www.example.com/index.php?cod=100&othercod=200)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to add another rule which handles this more specific request *before* the rule you already have in place. Something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# https://www.example.com/100/200
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?cod=$1&othercod=$2 [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# https://www.example.com/100
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ index.php?cod=$1 [L]
```